# Laravel migration vs model creation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is

```
php artisan make:model Test -m
```

equivalent to

```
php artisan make:migration create_tests_table --create=tests
```

?

Does make:model -m create a tests table?

Answer (score 4):

In  `php artisan make:model Test -m`, The `-m` flag will create a migration file for that model.

In `php artisan make:migration create_tests_table --create=tests`, the `--create` flag is the name of the table that will be created.

So yes, the `-m` option will create a migration file with a name like `TIMESTAMP_create_tests_table.php`

**Update**

If you find yourself in a situation when you doubt about commands, you can always run a command like this form your terminal: `php artisan help make:model`. You'll see an overview with some explenation about the extra options of that specific command.

Comment: -m will create the table as well?

Comment: `-m` only creates the migration file. To create the table in your database you still need to run `php artisan migrate` from your terminal.

Comment: @TheMan be sure to mark this answer as the right one if this helped you. Also, I've updated my answer with a tip in case you have similar questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not equivalent; they are very different. One is creating a model AND also creating a migration while the other is just creating a migration (both migrations include a table called tests). Bear in mind that creating a model and creating a table are not the same thing. From the docs: "The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database. Each database table has a corresponding "Model" which is used to interact with that table. Models allow you to query for data in your tables, as well as insert new records into the table."

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models